# How to create a folder in wordpress that will contain pages?

Tags: plugins, urls

What i am trying to do is to have some pages inside the folder within wordpress, i allow me to demonstrate. for example i want my url to look like this ***mydomain.com/awards/nominees*** I know how to do that in normal php website i would have  just created a folder called ***awards*** and inside the folder i will create another page called ***nomninees.php*** and the url will be like this ***mydomain.com/awards/nominees.php*** but i don't know how to accomplish this on wordpress i have tried to search but no luck.

Comment: Just to be clear: the problem is that you want two separate domains, domain.com and domain.hotels? And these should both be served by the same WordPress instance i.e. using the same database and posts table etc.?

Comment: No, i do not mean like that you got me wrong

Comment: OK, could you edit your post to explain what you do mean please? When you wrote "domain.hotels/hotel-a" did you mean "domain.com/hotels/hotel-a" ? I think that's the default behaviour for a custom post type, isn't it? Or did you mean "domain.com/hotel-a" ? Or something else?